# Java file conversion

Tags: java, android, video

I have a video recording in Android and the file generated is 3gp. I want to send mp4 file to server, how can I convert 3gp file to mp4, is there any jar for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These kind of conversions are usually CPU intensive, therefore the battery can be consumed pretty fast. Leave the conversion to the server. You may use Youtube for this